# Mirror repository won't work (The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden)

Tags: linux, yum, centos-6

I'm trying to find out why I still get the 403 when running the yum install command. I have created a repository mirror which can be read from remote machines.

Do you have any suggestions?

I have done the following:

```
 1. installed vsftpd
 2. created a repo in /var/ftp/pub/hdp/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.17
 3. ran createrepo in the  ../HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.17/repos/centos6/repodata/
 4. chmoded -R to 775
 5. added a new repo to /etc/yum.repos.d/hdp.conf  (triple checked the baseurl, it is correct, copy pasting it in a "curl baseurl" will work)
 6. disabled iptables, selinux 
 7. able to curl,wget,navigate in a browser to ftp://fqdn-hostname/pub/hdp/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.17/repos/centos6/repodata/repomd.xml
 8. ran yum clean all
 9. yum list will give me this error "ftp://fqdn-hostname/pub/hdp/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.17/repos/centos6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
```

PS. I actually went in python and using the pycurl module, called the URL and it gets an answer from the baseurl used in yum.repos.d.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `yum` have any more error information? Maybe you should copy and paste the `yum` output.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the issue eventually:

yum.conf was using a http proxy. Yum was also going through this proxy to access the local repository mirror, which was wrong in the case of hdp.conf.

This was fixed by adding  inside /etc/yum.repos.d/hdp.conf the following line for each repo:

```
proxy=_none_
```